# Laravel 5: blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I installed fresh copy of "Laravel 5" on my local machine via Laravel Installer, and it just working fine, but when I upload this copy to server, I get blank page, (using git)

system info:

```
1. server:  ubuntu 12.04
2. php:     PHP Version 5.6.11-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
3. laravel: version 5.1.7
4. my local machine OS: OSX yosemite 10.10.4
```

notes:

```
1. "/storage" has read/write permissions (777)
2. another installation of Laravel (v 4.2) installed on the server & working fine
```

any help?

Comment: can you show server logs?

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel-YYYY-MM-DD.log` for errors (replace `YYYY-MM-DD` with current date).

Comment: @Bogdan `storage/logs/` is empty

Comment: Occasionally, I need to run composer update after install because of WSOD. I've not yet worked out why but it seems to be randomly needed. Also, check storage/ permissions.

Comment: Check your server's logs.

Comment: I have not dev'd in laravel since 4.2, but you should try making sure that your app is not in production mode (APP_DEBUG=false, I believe), until it is live. Once in debug mode errors will show up on the screen, otherwise (at least in 4.2) they are in /app/storage/logs/laravel.log

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set proper permissions on `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders - check them directly on remote.

Comment: what is proper permission for `bootstrap/cache` ? "777"

Comment: I never use `777` for anything on my server. `775` is enough for both `storage` and `bootstrap/cache`.

Comment: storage => `drwxrwxrwx`, bootstrap/cache => `drwxrwxrwx` (still empty page appear)

Comment: Did you set those permissions recursively?

Comment: I used `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/` , `sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/`

Comment: Just go through http://laravel.com/docs/5.1 and see if you have all requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try run `composer install`.

We usually don't put the vendor (framework) folder inside git/svn, so you probably forget to "install" laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may get the error while you didn't configure your database through .env file.

Answer (score 0):

first check `php version in live server`

> 1. server:  ubuntu 12.04
> 2. php:     PHP Version 5.6.11-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
> 3. laravel: version 5.1.7
> 4. my local machine OS: OSX yosemite 10.10.4

Laravel require 5.5 and greater version 
so compare both server and laravel require version then it definately works.